# Let A be a commutative entire ring. Why does an automorphism of A[x] act as identity on A?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In Chapter 4 of Lang's Algebra, Exercise 8 states: "Let $A$ be a commutative entire ring and $x$ a variable over $A$. Let $a,b \in A$ and assume that $a$ is a unit in $A$. Show that the map $x \mapsto ax+b$ extends to a unique automorphism of $A[x]$ inducing the identity on $A$. What is the inverse automorphism?" I showed that the inverse is $a^{-1}(x-b)$. Then Exercise 9 states: "Show that every automorphism of $A[x]$ is of the type described in Exercise 8."

It is clear to me that we must have $x \mapsto ax+b$ for some $a,b$, but why must an automorphism of $A[x]$ induce the identity on $A$?

(I explained why this is not a duplicate of the problem referenced in the comments.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. I refer to that question, and then ask why every automorphism must induce the identity on $A$, which is not answered in that question.

Comment: @Stahl: it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I don't have Lang's book to hand, but if you take $B$ to be any integral domain (i.e., any "commutative entire ring" in Lang's terminology) and take $A$ to be the polynomial ring $B[y]$, then $A[x]$ admits an automorphism that maps $x$ to$y$ and $y$ to $x$. This automorphism clearly doesn't induce the identity on $A$. So if you have quoted Lang correctly, there is a mistake in the book.

Comment: If you have at least the revised 3rd edition, I would advise reading the questions a bit better. My copy of Lang gives exercise 9 as "Show that every autom. of $A[X]$ **inducing the identity on $A$** is of the form of exercise 8." (@RobArthan No, Lang is not wrong.)

Comment: That's bizarre. I do have revised 3rd edition.